# Direct sum - exists?

Tags: category-theory

I have a simple question: does the direct sum exist in the category of 1-dimensional vector spaces?

This is my argument: In the category of 1-dimensional vector spaces, the direct sum of two vector spaces does not exist.

In this category, every vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and any two non-isomorphic vector spaces are not related by a direct sum. If we try to define the direct sum of two 1-dimensional vector spaces, the resulting space would either be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{C}^2$, which are not 1-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. In a way, "1-dimensional vector space" doesn't make sense out of context; what makes sense is "1-dimensional as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space" and "1-dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space". For instance, $\mathbb{C}$ is 1-dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, but 2-dimensional as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Comment: Yes, the category of 1-dim vector space over R or C

Comment: Can you please give the definition of this category, i.e. objects and morphisms?

Comment: Do you mean "the category of 1-dim vector space of R or the category of 1-dim vector space over C", or "the category of 1-dim vector space over R or C"? The latter would be a bit weird.

Comment: The objects of this category are all 1-dimensional vector spaces, which are isomorphic to the vector space $\mathbb{F}$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$.

The morphisms of this category are linear transformations between these vector spaces. If we have two 1-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then any linear transformation $f: V \rightarrow W$ can be represented by a scalar $a \in \mathbb{F}$, such that $f(v) = a w$ for all $v \in V$ and $w \in W$.

Comment: Let’s stick to R

Comment: Ah, so it isn't one category $\mathcal C$. You have several categories $\mathcal C_{\Bbb F}$ that depend on some field $\mathbb F$. Then $\operatorname{Obj}\mathcal C_{\Bbb F}$ are the $\Bbb F$-vector spaces of dimension $1$ and $\operatorname{Mor}_{\mathcal C_{\Bbb F}}(X,Y)$ are the $\Bbb F$-linear maps between $X$ and $Y$. Right?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  How can you have a linear function between vector spaces defined over different fields?  And if the specification of the field is a crucial part of your category, that should be stated.

Comment: Ok Martin, "let's stick to R". In your previous comment, the representation of morphisms by "$f(v)=aw$ *for all* $v\in V$ and $w\in W$" makes no sense. In your main post, you cannot just say "the direct sum [in the category of R-vector spaces] of two lines is a plane, not a line, hence there is no direct sum in the category of R-lines". You have to examin the (non-)existence of direct sums (i.e. [coproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct)) *within* the category of R-lines.

Comment: That one-dimensional vector spaces are not closed under sums in vector spaces, is not sufficient. The coproducts in the new category might differ from the ones in the larger one (like fields inside integral domains)

Comment: @annebauval I am very aware of what you’re saying, sadly, there’s this rule on math stackexchange where you need to post a lengthy comment showing how you’ve put thought into a problem or otherwise you get downvoted, so I just spouted out some intuition which I don’t think is useless anyway

Comment: I think this rule is not so bad, and you should have included some deeper thoughts, especially if you are very aware of what they should be. Downvotes can also sanction dummy attempts.

Comment: I think brevity is the soul of wit, but it’s OK to agree to disagree

Comment: @MarcOlschok As I've explained in my answer, because linear maps form commutative monoids and composition of morphisms is bihomomoprhic, products and coproducts canonically coincide as biproducts and are absolute. In particular, a biproduct in a subcategory is is also a biproduct in the category if the subcategory's morphisms include zero morphisms and are closed under addition. Thus, that $1$-dimensional vector spaces are not closed under under sums in vector spaces is actually sufficient to conclude their subcategory does not have direct sums.

Comment: @Vladimir Sotiriv: Yes, I was referring only to the OPs initial attempt. I see now that your answer provides the missing argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the following setup: we have some field $\mathbb K$ and consider the
full subcategory ${\cal C}$ of $Vect_{\mathbb K}$ that consists of one-dimensional
vector spaces.

This category does not have coproducts.

(1) every morphism in ${\cal C}$ is either a zero map or an isomorphism.

(2) assume that two objects $V$ and $W$ have a coproduct in ${\cal  C}$.
This means that there is a coproduct diagram

$$ V \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} X \stackrel{j}{\longleftarrow} W $$

such that for any pair of morphism $f\colon V\to Y$ and $g\colon W\to Y$
there is a unique morphism $h=(f\mid g)$ with
$f = h\circ i$ and $g=h\circ j$.

(3) Take $Y=V$, $f=id_V$ and $g=0$.
This forces $i\neq 0$, $(id_V\mid 0)$ isomorphism and hence $j=0$.

(4) Take $Y=W$, $f=0$ and $g=id_W$.
This forces $j\neq 0$, $(0\mid id_W)$ isomorphism and hence $i=0$.

Now, (3) and (4) contradict each other.

Comment: This forces $i\neq 0$, $(id_V,0)$ isomorphism and hence $j=0$. I don’t understand this, and I’d be very grateful if you could explain me what “ $(id_V,0)$” means as well as why “ $i\neq 0$” is forced to hold, and similarly for $j=0$

Comment: Sorry, I had mistyped: $(id_V,0)$ should be $(id_V\mid 0)$. If $i=0$ then the required equation  $(id_V\mid 0) \circ i = id_V$ would not be satisfied. So $i\neq 0$. By the same reasoning $(id_V\mid 0)\neq 0$. By  (1) both maps must be isomorphisms. But then $j$ cannot be an isomorphism because otherwise  $(id_V\mid 0) \circ j = 0$ would not be satisfied.  So $j=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The following deserves no votes. It is nothing more than a "concrete" version of @MarcOlschok 's answer.

In the category of one-dimensional vector spaces over a fixed field $K,$

- every object is isomorphic to $K;$
- every morphism $f$ from $K$ to itself is determined by the scalar $f(1).$

Therefore, proving that it has no coproduct is equivalent to proving that there is no $(a,b)\in K^2$ (determining two morphisms from $K$ to $K$) such that
$$\forall(c,d)\in K^2\quad\exists!e\in K\quad c=ea\text{ and }d=eb.$$
If such a pair $(a,b)$ existed, for $(c,d)=(1,0)$ we should have $ea=1$ hence  $b=ad=0.$ But for $d=1$ we should have $eb=1$ hence $b\ne0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, Anne, I understand your deriving of the contradiction, but why, given objects are isomorphic to K and automorphisms are determined by their values at 1, is it the case that “therefore” no coproduct $\iff$ there is no $(a,b)\in$K$^2$ satisfying your condition?

Comment: Because all objects $V,W,X,Y$ considered in Marc Olschok 's answer can be assumed wlog to be $K,$ and then all morphisms are determined by scalars, and composition becomes multiplication. E.g. Mark's $f = h\circ i$ is rewritten $c=ea.$

Answer (score -1):

Your argument is incomplete.

Implicitly, you're relying on the fact that the category of vector spaces is enriched in commutative monoids: each set of morphisms between two objects has the structure of a commutative monoid, and composition of morphisms is a homomorphism of such in each variable.

In this situation, the direct sum of two objects $A_1$ and $A_2$ is a biproduct: an object $B$ equipped with pairs of morphisms $i_j\colon A_j\to B$ and $\pi_j\colon A_j\to B$ satisfying the equations

1. $\pi_j\circ i_k=1_{A_j}=1_{A_k}$ if $j=k$ and $0\colon A_k\to A_j$ otherwise.
2. $i_1\circ\pi_1+i_2\circ\pi_2=1_B$.

Indeed, given a pair of coproduct coprojections $i_j\colon A_j\to B$, the existence part of the universal property of the coproduct gives unique morphisms $\pi_j\colon B\to A_j$ satisfying the first set of equations.
But the first set of equations implies $(i_1\circ\pi_1+i_2\circ\pi_2)\circ i_j=i_j$, whence the uniqueness part of the universal property of the coproduct implies the second equation.  Conversely, $(f_1\circ\pi_1+f_2\circ\pi_2)\circ i_j=f_j$, and $f\circ i_1\circ\pi_1+f\circ i_2\circ\pi_2=f\circ 1_B=f$ show that $i_j\colon A_j\to B$ are coproduct coprojections.

In particular, since the biproduct is given by equations alone, the direct sum is absolute, so the structure of a direct sum in a subcategory is also a structure of a direct sum in the category. Thus, if the subcategory of $1$-dimensional subspaces had direct sums, then the direct sum of $1$-dimensional spaces would be $1$-dimensional in the category of all vector spaces.

If the direct sum of $1$-dimensional spaces were $1$-dimensional, then we can take $A_1=A_2=B$ (since all $1$-dimensional spaces are isomorphic) and consider the above equations as ones involving endomorphisms of the same object. In particular, such an object is its own biproduct if and only if we have

1. $\pi_ji_k=1$ if $j=k$ and $0$ otherwise
2. $i_1\pi_1+i_2\pi_2=1$.

for elements $\pi_j,i_j$ of the semi-ring $R$ of endomorphisms of the object.

Note that for the object being a $1$-dimensional vector space over a field, or more generally a free module of rank $1$ over a semi-ring, then $R$ is that field or semi-ring.

We see that such equations cannot hold for a non-trivial commutative ring $R$, as then $1=i_1\circ\pi_1+i_2\circ\pi_2=\pi_1\circ i_1+\pi_2\circ i_2=2$. They also cannot hold for a non-trivial semi-ring in which every non-zero element has a right inverse as then $\pi_1i_2=0=\pi_2i_1$ implies $\pi_1=\pi_2=0$ and hence $0=1$.

In other words, free modules of rank $1$ over commutative rings and semi-rings in which every non-zero element has an inverse are never also of rank $2$.

More generally, finite ranks of free modules are well-defined if there are no matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfying $AB=1_n$ and $BA=1_m$ where $1_n$ and $1_m$ are identity matrices of different sizes. The above equations have $A=\begin{pmatrix}\pi_1\\\pi_2\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}i_1&i_2\end{pmatrix}$. Since the condition is equational, it follows that a semi-ring has well-defined finite ranks of free modules if it admits a homomorphism into such a non-trivial semi-ring.